# I want to divide areas using style components

Tags: css, sass, styled-components

I tried to divide areas using flexibility. But it was not successful.
plz help me..TT

```
const BodyContainer = styled.div`
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    flex: 0.7;
`;

const SideBackground = styled.div`
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    flex: 0.3;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try that.

```
 const MainContainer = styled.div`
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   height: 100vh;
`;

const BodyContainer = styled.div`
   flex: 0.7;
   background-color: red;
`;
const SideBackground = styled.div`
   flex: 0.3;
   background-color: black;
`;
```